# Why do projective structures correspond to quadratic forms?

Tags: surfaces, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, cartan-geometry

So I'm trying to read Feng Luo's paper "Monodromy Groups of Projective Structures on Punctured Surfaces", but I'm stumped on the first page. A **projective structure** on a Riemann surface is defined to be an (equivalence class of) atlas of holomorphic coordinate charts whose composition maps are restrictions of projective transformations - in other words, $S = \bigcup_a U_a$ with $\phi_a: U_a \rightarrow V_a \subset \mathbb{C},$ with $\phi_b \circ \phi_a^{-1}$ a Mobius map.

On the other hand, a **holomorphic quadratic differential** is something that can locally be written as $f(z) dz^2$, such that $f$ is holomorphic if $z$ is a holomorphic coordinate - so, with a holomorphic atlas $U_a$, $\phi_a = z_a$, we have a collection of functions $f_a : V_a \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $$\frac{f_a}{f_b} = \left( \frac{dz_b}{dz_a}  \right)^2 $$ for all $a,b$.

The statement is then that the set of all projective structures on a Riemann surface is an affine space over the vector space of all holomorphic quadratic differentials. So, given a projective structure $\lbrace \phi_a \rbrace_a,$ there is a way to "add" any holomorphic quadratic differential $\lbrace f_a \rbrace_a$ to it, to obtain a new projective structure, such that any two projective structures differ by a holomorphic quadratic differential in this way.

Can anyone help me to see how this works?

Comment: You could clarify the way you get an holomorphic quadratic differential from such a projective structure. Is there $f(z)dz^2 \mapsto f(\phi_b^{-1}\circ \phi_a)dz^2$ ? And I would try assuming $S = \mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ for some discrete subgroup $\Gamma \subset GL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: But I don't know what that way is.....also, if projective structures form the affine space and HQDs form the acting vector space, surely a projective structure wouldn't tell us an HQD? A point in an affine space doesn't give us a point in the acting vector space in general....